# Segmentation error in simple inheritance related code

Tags: c++

Shortened code I wrote for learning purposes. Still the way it is, it doesn't work properly.
Removing last line (&&) it works OK, but with it, code doesn't reach line noted as ##, expressing
segmentation error, after the "BazOnly" text displayed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace nek{
    class Baz{
        int num; 
        std::string  str;
        public:
        Baz(){cout<<"BazOnly"<<endl;}
        string setstr(string& val){  
            //str.assign(val);
            num= 7;
        }
    }; 
}

namespace drg{
    class Deriv: nek::Baz{       
        public:
        Deriv(char ch){cout<<"DerivChar"<<endl;}
    };
};

int main(){
    nek::Baz b;     
    string priv{"zik"};
    b.setstr(priv);    
    cout<<"Passed here"<<endl; //##
    drg::Deriv dc{'A'};  // &&
}
```

Compiled with g++ (option std=gnu++11), Ubuntu 16 on Virtual Box.
Question is what could be the reason for such behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    string setstr(string& val){  
        //str.assign(val);
        num= 7;
    }
```

This method is declared as returning a `std::string`, but nothing actually gets returned from it. This is undefined behavior.

Most modern C++ compilers will warn you about this. If yours' did, this is an example of why you cannot ignore warning messages from your compiler, even if it did successfully compile your code.

Comment: Huh- must confess it's big mistake. No excuse for me, but just to mention, there were no warnings (VS Code Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: @Djole • did you have warnings enabled?  Some compilers will only emit required warnings unless additional warnings are requested to be enabled.  For clang++, I use these `-Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -pedantic`.

Comment: It came upon my mind while taping last message. Probably I didn't. I'll double check it.